# Is "Even so, we’ll keep walking" a valid sentence as a book title?

Tags: sentence, titles, books

I was struggling to find a good title for a fiction I write, and a found this sentence in the english subtitles of a song. I'd like to know if it's a valid sentence as a standalone, or if it needs to be a part of a full-lenght sentence.

Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: It should probably be "Even so, we'll keep walking." but unless one of the scholarly regulars on this site dispute it, it is a complete sentence.

Comment: It's fine, and a valid sentence, but please insert a comma after "so": "Even so, we'll keep walking". It's actually quite a thought-provoking title.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the comma when writing my question, sorry. Thank you for your quick answers.

Comment: A book title doesn't have to be a sentence.  In fact, probably fewer than 10% are.

Comment: Just to note: the comma isn’t actually required as such; you can go without it. If you leave it out, though, you risk the reader parsing the sentence as meaning ‘even [so that we’ll keep walking]’ instead of ‘[even so] [we’ll keep walking]’. I agree it’s quite a nice title.

Comment: "Glibnix Perfundo" is a valid book title.

Comment: You have an inalienable right to use any set of words as your book title. Grammar is of no consequence there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an *Eats Shoots and Leaves* effect (Google the title), your proposed title is pretty good as is.

Otherwise, the answer by @James Greene is a sound bet.

Answer (score -1):

yes but it should be

Even so, we'll keep walking